# how to intregrate wordpress for this piece of navigation menu?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is my Html header code for navigation menu. I want to intregrate this Html format for my wordpress theme. I have intregated logo but now i am stuck in Nav menu. I am looking forwad to integrate nav menu with dropdown child menu with the same class used for the tags in nav menu

```
<header class="header" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="1">
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Cardiff + PAGE Group"></a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About You <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Create Profile <span class="linkedin-icon"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> </a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Portal</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="our-clients.php">Our Clients  </a></li>
              <li><a href="opportunity.php">Opportunities </a></li>

              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="aboutc+pg.php" class="dropdown-toggle"  data-hover="dropdown" >About C+PG <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                  <li><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
                  <li><a href="career.php">Career Advice</a></li>
                  <li><a href="interview-tips.php">Interviewing Tips</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"  data-hover="dropdown" >Strategic Partner <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="http://www.teamstub.com/" target="_blank">TeamStub</a></li>
                  <li><a href="http://www.brokeragenation.com/" target="_blank">Brokerage Nation</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Widget Credit</a></li>
                  <li><a href="http://www.ptsconsulting.com/" target="_blank">PTS Consulting</a></li>
                  <li><a href="https://www.upwardlyglobal.org" target="_blank">Upwardly Global</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header> <!-- end / header -->
```

Comment: If you are new please refer Theme section in wordpress codex.

Comment: <?php
                      $args=array(
                          'theme_location'=>'primary',
                          'before'=>'',
                          'menu_class'=>'nav navbar-nav navbar-right ',

                      );
                      ?>
                         <?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?>

Comment: You can add your code into header.php in theme folder

Comment: this is not proper way it just hack.

Comment: could you tell me the right way to do it?? give some refrence or hints

Comment: Yes sure.I will

Comment: Go to Theme folder->open header.php

Comment: what is your theme name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step :1 - To add a custom navigation menu, the first thing you need to do is register your new navigation menu by adding this code to your theme’s `functions.php` file.

```
function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('my-custom-menu',__( 'My Custom Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );
```

Step : 2 - we need to display the new navigation menu in your WordPress theme.

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'my-custom-menu', 
    'container_class' => 'custom-menu-class' ) ); 
?>
```

The theme location is the name that we selected in the previous step.

Step : 3 - Create your custom style and attached using `wp_enqueue_style` or Create child theme to override functionality.

Need a reference check this: 
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-navigation-menus-in-wordpress-3-0-themes/

Comment: @Anuj Shrestha Please mark it complete if this work for you.

Comment: my style is bootstrap :(

Comment: it doesn't metter

Comment: I don't want to change my style.css is it any other way?

Comment: can you please tell which theme are you using?

Comment: it is my own theme not a child theme or any other theme

Comment: If you want to add something without change in style.css then you have to create -child theme or create css file other then the style.css and wp_enqueue_style to attached it

Comment: What about walker class?

Comment: Sorry,I will try my best as wp developer

Comment: Yeah I work with walker function and the problem is solved.